# thread racing when working with vector of data in the thread function

Tags: c++, multithreading, opencv, c++11, vector

Being an early stage c++/thread coder I am having some hard time with thread racing in one of my test functions and would truly appreciate some feedback.

My parent() function takes in as input a rather large vector of images (cv::Mat from openCV) and the task is to compute an operator on each one separately (e.g. dilation). I wrote a loop that creates threads using a worker() function and passes on each thread a subset of my input vector.

The result from each thread is to be stored on that input subset vector. My problem is that I cannot retrieve it back from within the parent().

As an alternative I passed the entire vector to worker() with start and end indices for each thread but then I run into some serious thread racing issues consuming more time than the serial approach.

Please see my code below.

```
std::vector<cv::Mat> worker(std::vector<cv::Mat>& ctn);
std::vector<cv::Mat> worker(std::vector<cv::Mat>& ctn) {

  int erosion_type = cv::MORPH_RECT;
  int erosion_size = 5;

  cv::Mat element = cv::getStructuringElement( erosion_type,
    cv::Size( 2*erosion_size + 1, 2*erosion_size+1 ),
    cv::Point( erosion_size, erosion_size ) );

  this_mutex.lock();
  for(uint it=0; it<ctn.size(); ++it) {
    cv::erode(ctn[it], ctn[it], element);
  }
  this_mutex.unlock();
  return ctn;
}


void parent(std::vector<cv::Mat>& imageSet) {

  auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

  const auto processor_count = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();

  std::vector<std::thread> threads;

  const int grainsize = imageSet.size() / processor_count;

  uint work_iter = 0;
  std::vector<cv::Mat> target; // holds the output vector

  // create the threads
  for(uint it=0; it<processor_count-1; ++it) {
    std::vector<cv::Mat> subvec(imageSet.begin() + work_iter, imageSet.begin() + work_iter + grainsize);
    threads.emplace_back([&,it]() {
      std::vector<cv::Mat> tmp = worker(subvec);
      target.insert(target.end(), tmp.begin(), tmp.end());
    });
    work_iter += grainsize;
  }

  // create the last thread for the remainder of the vector elements
  std::vector<cv::Mat> subvec(imageSet.begin() + work_iter, imageSet.end());
  int it = processor_count-1;
  threads.emplace_back([&,it]() {
    std::vector<cv::Mat> tmp = worker(subvec);
    target.insert(target.end(), tmp.begin(), tmp.end());
  });

  // join the threads
  for(int i=0; i<threads.size(); ++i) {
    threads[i].join();
  }

  auto end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
  std::chrono::duration<double> elapsed_seconds = end-start;
  std::cout << "elapsed time: " << elapsed_seconds.count() << "s\n";

  // try to reconstruct the output  
  imageSet.clear();
  for(int i=0; i<target.size(); ++i) {
    imageSet.push_back(target[i]);
  }
}
```

In this code the statement `target.insert(target.end(), tmp.begin(), tmp.end())` is meant to concatenate the target[ ] vector with the result of each thread but it does not execute in time thus I get an empty target[] at the end.

Any ideas how to get target[] to collect all tmp[]s?

Comment: Its not clear exactly what your problem is to me, but my feedback is this: `Don't work directly with raw threads unless you have to. There are std library abstractions and other libraries such as boost.`

Comment: Thanks @taekahn; the problem is to collect the output subvectors and stitch them together to one of the same size as the input. My code above fails yo do that because the vector concatenation inside the emplace_back executes before the subvec[] is updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where you thinking something like this? 
This processes them all individually, but you can chunk it up however you want and return a vector from the lamda if you want.
Note: This is in C++11, since that is what you tagged. If you have access to 17, this becomes a whole lot simpler.

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>
#include <future>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> input{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};

    for(const auto& item : input)
    {
        std::cout << item << " ";
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::vector<std::future<int>> threads{};

    for(const auto& item : input)
    {
        threads.push_back(std::async(std::launch::async, [&item]{
            return item * 100;
        }));
    }

    std::vector<int> output{};

    for(auto& thread : threads)
    {
        output.push_back(thread.get());
    }

    for(const auto& item : output)
    {
        std::cout << item << " ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: that is a very elegant solution. Thanks Taekahn. I was wondering in the case of images, where the input and thus the return argument of the Lambda needs to be `std::vector<cv::Mat>` is the change the declaration of threads from what is above to `std::vector<std::future<std::vector<cv::Mat>>> threads{};`  legit?

Comment: Yes, that would be valid. Though you might want to use aliases. `std::vector<std::future<std::vector<cv::Mat>>>` is hard to read :)

Answer (score 0):

One result (`res`) for each thread.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cassert>

void threadFunction (std::vector<int> &speeds, int start, int end, std::vector<int>& res);

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> images (100000);
    auto processor_count = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();
    auto step = images.size() / processor_count;
    auto startFrom = 0;

    // one result vector (res) for each thread (t).
    std::vector<std::thread>t;
    std::vector<std::vector<int>>res (processor_count);
    // Start the threads
    for (auto i = 0; i < processor_count; ++i) 
    {
        auto th = std::thread(threadFunction, std::ref(images), startFrom, startFrom+step, std::ref(res[i]));
        t.push_back(std::move(th));
        startFrom += step;
    }

    // Join
    std::for_each(begin(t), end(t), [](std::thread &t)
    {
        assert(t.joinable());
        t.join();
    });

    // Results here. Each thread puts the results in res[i];
    return 0;
}

void threadFunction (std::vector<int> &images, int start, int end, std::vector<int>& res)
{
    for (int i = start; i <= end; ++i)
        res.push_back(images[i]);
}
```

Comment: that was sharp to the point. Thank you very much Kasper. As a minor remark the line `std::vector<std::thread>t (processor_count);` needs to be `std::vector<std::thread> t;` instead.

Comment: Trying out that code I measured my speedup to be approximately 5x on 16 threads. Any idea what might be causing this?

Comment: When running that code on 16 threads, it executed 5 times faster compared to my serial alternative running on a single thread. I was expecting this to be a bit faster, in the order of 10 times faster. Is there something Evident that slows things down?

Comment: Ah, good point. We're in the space of optimization. I've quickly written that code without that in mind. I'll think about that